# When the Volley Request is canceled

Tags: android, request, android-volley

I have a Request in a activity, I need to know if the request is canceled, so I checked in the `onResponse()` method by using `Request.isCanceled()`, but it return false. I have no idea when the request is really canceled, and I have read the code, still no answer.

Comment: `I want to hide the loading dialog after all the requests canceled, so I need to check if the request is canceled.` if you do not cancel your request it wont be canceled.

Answer (score 8):

The code reveals ALL.

It really depends on the timing.

Once `request.cancel()` is called, the request is flagged for cancellation and it all depends on what state it's in. There are 4 options:

1. `cancel()` is called before cache check - request is discarded by the `CacheDispatcher` in its `run` loop (line 94)
2. `cancel()` is called, on a request that doesn't have a cached response after the cache check, but before the request is actually performed - request is discarded by the `NetworkDispatcher` in its `run` loop (line 102).
3. `cancel()` is called after request has been sent, but before a response arrives - `ExecutorDelivery` discards the response upon arrival (line 92) and **DOES NOT NOTIFY THE LISTENER**. That means that when `onResponse` or `onError` are called, the request has not been canceled, and checking for it there, like you did, will ALWAYS return false.
4. `cancel()` is called after delivery - nothing happens, it's too late.

I didn't understand your circumstance exactly, who is canceling the request, and why are you checking, but hopefully that's enough info to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for heping. Actually I have serveral Request with the same tag in a Activity, and I show a loading dialog before requests execute, now I want to hide the loading dialog after all the requests canceled, so I need to check if the request is canceled. But as your answer, I can't check in the "onResponse()" method. I will try another way, or could you give any opinions

Comment: Is there some sort of work around for number 3? Please see my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577601/how-do-you-cancel-a-volley-request-that-has-already-started