# How do you cancel the writing to a ByteOutputStream in a custom request's getBody method?

Tags: android, android-volley

My custom request object is a MultiPartPost Request and has a CountingOutputStream so that I can observe the current upload progress. I am using the custom Request class from this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28144660/1744379

I want to give the user the freedom to cancel it while the upload is ongoing, so it is useful to have the `CountingOutputStream`, but while I CAN cancel the request (I know as I logged it and the request returns true from its `isCancelled()` method), the writing to the `ByteOutputStream` is still ongoing.

Is there a way to cancel it and then like throw aside the call to `getBody()`?